# Check PyQt/PySide method signature

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, signature

[QWidget (PySide)](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget) constructor accepts `f` keyword, but [QWizard](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWizard.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.QWizard) has `flags` argument instead of `f`. Is it possible to inspect method signature beforehand? I want to be able to pass flags to any QWidget subclass.

Comment: Take a look at [inspect.getfullargspec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec).

Comment: @cpburnz unfortunately it's *args, **kwargs: `FullArgSpec(args=['self'], varargs='args', varkw='kwargs', defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})`

Comment: That's unfortunate. I wondered if it would work or not because it's a Python wrapper around a C++ framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget) accepts `f`, and [QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.QDialog) also accepts `f`. [QWizard](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWizard.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.QWizard) appears to be the odd one out that uses `flags`. Since [inspect.getfullargspec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec) does not work with PySide objects, I'd recommend making a helper function if you need to determine this at run time. The helper will have to determine whether to use the *f* or *flags* keyword argument based upon a known list of widget classes.

```python
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

FLAGS_WIDGETS = (QtWidgets.QWizard,)

def flags_kwarg(cls, flags):
    if issubclass(cls, FLAGS_WIDGETS):
        key = 'flags'
    else:
        key = 'f'
    return {key: flags}
```

This can then be used as:

```python
from PySide2 import QtCore

cls = QtWidgets.QWizard # or some other widget class
flags = QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags()
kwargs = flags_kwarg(cls, flags)

widget = cls(parent, **kwargs)
```